# Dependency Injection with classes which are created often

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependency-injection, ecmascript-6

I have a question about dependency injection and best practices when using simple classes which are meant to be created often, which have dependencies on external services. Here's a (vastly) simplified version of what I'm working on:

#### app.js

```
import {Factory} from './factory.js';
import {Convert} from './convert.js';

let convert = new Convert();
let factory = new Factory({ convert });

// assume this is being imported and executed somewhere
export function run() {
    let avengers = [
          factory.person({ first: 'Iron', last: 'Man' })
        , factory.person({ first: 'Captain', last: 'America' })
        , factory.person({ first: 'Scarlet', last: 'Witch' })
        , factory.person({ first: 'Black', last: 'Panther' })
    ];
    console.log(avengers);
}
```

#### convert.js

```
export class Convert {
    toString(val) {
        if (!val)
            return '';
        return val.toString();
    }
}
```

#### person.js

```
export class Person {
    constructor({
        convert,
        first,
        last
    }) {
        this.convert = convert;
        this.first   = this.convert.toString(first);
        this.last    = this.convert.toString(last);
    }
}
```

#### factory.js

```
import {Person} from './person.js';

export class Factory {

    constructor({ convert }) {
        this.convert = convert;
    }

    person(obj) {
        obj.convert = this.convert;
        return new Person(obj);
    }
}
```

My main interest is that class `Person` has a dependency on a function located on an instance of class `Convert`. My question is this -- is this taking dependency injection too far? Am I better off just importing an instantiated version of `Convert` into `Person.js` and referencing it directly? I know that will work, but I was trying to avoid coupling the two classes without a nice way to override. I definitely don't like what I have written here, since `Convert` will be defined on each `Person`, which is worse than coupled classes in my opinion.

I had started working on modularizing one of my libraries to decouple classes and use dependency injection, but my pattern broke down when I ran across an instance similar to this. Any suggestions are definitely welcome.

Side note, I know in this example I could just use the `Convert` methods inside the `Factory` instead of inside `Person` -- that doesn't work for my actual project, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I better off just importing an instantiated version of Convert into Person.js and referencing it directly? I know that will work, but I was trying to avoid coupling the two classes without a nice way to override. I definitely don't like what I have written here, since Convert will be defined on each Person, which is worse than coupled classes in my opinion.

There is nothing wrong with requiring a data conversion service. The problem is coupling the conversion service with the `Person` class. This coupling should occur in the `Factory` class instead.

Furthermore, you haven't coupled the classes together. ECMA Script is a dynamically typed language. At worst you've coupled the `Person` class to an object supporting the same public interface as the `Convert` class.

Solving this dilemma is pretty simple. The data conversion should happen in the factory:

**factory.js**

```
import {Person} from './person.js';

export class Factory {

    constructor({ convert }) {
        this.convert = convert;
    }

    person(obj) {
        obj.first = this.convert.toString(obj.first);
        obj.last = this.convert.toString(obj.last);

        return new Person(obj);
    }
}
```

**person.js**

```
export class Person {
    constructor({ first, last }) {
        this.first = first;
        this.last = last;
    }
}
```

This keeps your `Person` constructor clean and straight forward. The messiness of converting data types is encapsulated in the `Factory` class where it belongs, and the `Person` class no longer has a dependency on the `Convert` class.

Comment: I agree, but unfortunately I can't move all of my logic to the factory in my actual code, as the class I'm actually creating needs to make use of the dependency (`Convert` in this case) inside a function which lives on the dependent class (`Person`) -- sorry, I probably over-simplified the question a bit by moving the use of the dependency to the constructor, but in reality it's in quite a few other places. That being said, I will most likely accept this as the answer, as I think it's as close as I can get.